# How to limit webview to open only a specific set of url?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows Store app which involves working with a `Webview`, I'm trying to let user access specific set of web pages inside and limit the `Webview` to load the only specified set of URLs, until now I haven't came across any post that will help, is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing for your app to target just windows 8.1, you can use the new NavigationStarting event (which include the target uri and a cancel parameter).
If you want to target windows 8, than there no really good solution. Probably the best is to register the LoadCompleted event and do a GoBack.

Comment: Have to use Windows 8.

The problem with load completed event is it only fires 1 time i.e. when the webview control has completed loading the page for the first time, but nothing happens when you navigate inside the webview after that point.

Comment: I'm not talking about the loaded event, I'm talking of LoadCompleted which fire each time after you have navigated to a new page

Comment: Otherwise if that don't work for you, you can try injecting javascript using the InvokeScript function. In a generic way the only I have seen is detecting when you navigate away but you will not get the target uri. If you have a fix set of pages you can visit, maybe you can manually add event handler to all the buttons.

Comment: Here is a link to a description on how to detect Navigating that I have seen : http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/04/21/Limitations-of-the-WebView-in-Windows-8-Metro-Apps.aspx